# How can I remove elements of a nested list based on a condition?

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
l =[
   ['abgegeben', 'abgegeb', 339],
   ['abgegebene', 'abgegeb', 46], 
   ['abgegebenen', 'abgegeb', 30], 
   ['abgegebenes', 'abgegeb', 4],
   ['abgefahren', 'abgefahr', 58], 
   ['abgefahrene', 'abgefahr', 4],   
   ['abgefahrenen', 'abgefahr', 4], 
   ['abgefahrener', 'abgefahr', 4]
   ]
```

As you can see the second entry of the sublists is the stem of the first entry.
Since the stems are identical I want to keep the sublist of the stem with the highest count (339 and 58) and remove the others like this:

```
l =[
   ['abgegeben', 'abgegeb', 339],
   ['abgefahren', 'abgefahr', 58]
   ]
```

My list contains several ten thousand sublists. 
I already tried to compare the entries with the `max` function and append the results into a new list but that did not work out.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

f = lambda x:x[1]
[max(g, key=lambda x: x[-1]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)]
```

Note: if you are sure the second entries are sorted, you can skip the `sorted`.

Output:

```
[['abgefahren', 'abgefahr', 58], 
 ['abgegeben', 'abgegeb', 339]]
```

Explanation from innermost:

1. `sorted(l, key=f)`: Sort the `l` based on the `f`, which is to use second entry of each sublist in `l`. This is because `itertools.groupby` cannot handle unsorted list (it then makes separated groups despite having same key).
2. `groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)`: It then groups the sorted sublist using the same key as `sorted`. So instead of having same lambda twice, it looks better having single key function `f`.
3. `[max(g, key=lambda x:x[-1]) ...]`: Finally `max` returns the maximum sublist among the groups created by `groupby`. This time, the max was calculated using the last element of sublist so new lambda was used.

Comment: Hi @Chris, thanks for your answer. However your solution gives just the sublist with the highest count in the whole list. But I need the sublist for every stem with the highest count. Sorry if I was unclear in the question, I edited it.

Comment: Thanks worked great! One question: what is the meaning  of ```x[-1]```  in ```key=lambda x: x[-1])```?

Comment: @gython It means to find max _based on_ the comparison of the **last** item; i.e first from the end = -1

Comment: Hi @Chris, if you have the time I have another question: Did I understand it correctly that ```sorted(l, key=f)``` is the data to group and ```key=f``` is the grouping key? And if so why does ```key=f``` appear two times in ```groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f)]```?

Comment: @gython I've updated some explanation. Hope it makes answer clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

Or use `itertools.groupby`:

```
print([max(l, key=lambda x: x[-1]) for _, l in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[1])])
```

Output:

```
[['abgegeben', 'abgegeb', 339], ['abgefahren', 'abgefahr', 58]]
```

Comment: Hi @U10-Forward, thanks for your answer. However your solution gives just the sublist with the highest count in the whole list. But I need the sublist for every stem with the highest count. Sorry if I was unclear in the question, I edited it.

Comment: @gython Edited mine please check!

Comment: Thanks worked great! One question: what is the meaning  of ```x[-1]```  in ```key=lambda x: x[-1])```?

Comment: @gython It gets the last item of the list

Comment: @gython It would be nice if you could accept one of the answers.